# Setting different color to each item in List ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, listview

i've recently started learning android and came across this problem:
after clicking button im displaying new TextView to my ListView - it's a new payment for one of 3 ppl: Lukasz/Marcelina/Karolina - and I want to make every Lukasz' payment appear RED, every Marcelinas BLUE and Karolinas - GREEN

What I tried so far was putting value to a flag (1, 2 or 3) in every CASE in ONCLICK method and adding if statement

```
        if(flag==1){
            holder.osoba.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        else if(flag==2){
            holder.osoba.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }else if (flag == 3) {
            holder.osoba.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
```

but it turns out I dont set color to a particular item in my List but to all the items (for example when i press 'lukas' it will give me RED Lukasz's payment, but then when I do a Marcelina's new payment which should be BLUE (and Lukasz should star RED) it makes every payment in the list BLUE. Any ideas how to set different color of each List element ?

my Main Activity looks like this:

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
private int flag = 0;
private TextView sum;
private Button addButton;
private EditText addPrice;
private TextView sumPerPerson;
private EditText description;

private ListaWplat listaWplat;

private RadioGroup czlonek;
private RadioButton lukaszRadioButton;
private RadioButton marcelinaRadioButton;
private RadioButton karolinaRadioButton;

private TextView sumaLukasz;
private TextView sumaMarcelina;
private TextView sumaKarolina;
private float tempLukasz = 0;
private float tempMarcelina = 0;
private float tempKarolina = 0;

public float getTempMarcelina() {
    return tempMarcelina;
}

public float getTempLukasz() {
    return tempLukasz;
}

public float getTempKarolina() {
    return tempKarolina;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.suma);
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    addPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dodajCene);
    sumPerPerson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sumaNaOsobe);
    description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);

    sumaLukasz = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sumaLukasz);
    sumaMarcelina = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sumaMarcelina);
    sumaKarolina = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sumaKarolina);

    czlonek = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.czlonek);
    lukaszRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.lukaszRadioButton);
    marcelinaRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.marcelinaRadioButton);
    karolinaRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.karolinaRadioButton);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    int checkedRadioButtonId = czlonek.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    switch (checkedRadioButtonId) {
        case R.id.lukaszRadioButton:
            if (lukaszRadioButton.isChecked()) {
                try {
                    tempLukasz += valueOf(addPrice.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
                // dodanie $ do sumy lukasza
                String sumaLukasza = getString(R.string.sumaLukasz);
                sumaLukasza = String.format(sumaLukasza, getTempLukasz());
                sumaLukasz.setText(sumaLukasza + " zl");
                flag = 1;


                NowaWplata nowaWplata = new NowaWplata(lukaszRadioButton.getText().toString(), addPrice.getText().toString(), description.getText().toString());

                listaWplat.setWplaty(nowaWplata);
                setListAdapter(new NewPaymentAdapter(this, R.layout.nowa_wplata, listaWplat.getWplaty()));
            }
            break;

        case R.id.marcelinaRadioButton:
            if (marcelinaRadioButton.isChecked()) {
                try {
                    tempMarcelina += valueOf(addPrice.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
                // dodanie $ do sumy marceliny
                String sumaMarceliny = getString(R.string.sumaMarcelina);
                sumaMarceliny = String.format(sumaMarceliny, getTempMarcelina());
                sumaMarcelina.setText(sumaMarceliny + " zl");
                flag=2;

                NowaWplata nowaWplata = new NowaWplata(marcelinaRadioButton.getText().toString(), addPrice.getText().toString(), description.getText().toString());

                listaWplat.setWplaty(nowaWplata);
                setListAdapter(new NewPaymentAdapter(this, R.layout.nowa_wplata, listaWplat.getWplaty()));

            }
            break;

        case R.id.karolinaRadioButton:
            if (karolinaRadioButton.isChecked()) {
                try {
                    tempKarolina += valueOf(addPrice.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
                // dodanie $ do sumy karoliny
                String sumaKaroliny = getString(R.string.sumaKarolina);
                sumaKaroliny = String.format(sumaKaroliny, getTempKarolina());
                sumaKarolina.setText(sumaKaroliny + " zl");
                flag=3;

                NowaWplata nowaWplata = new NowaWplata(karolinaRadioButton.getText().toString(), addPrice.getText().toString(), description.getText().toString());

                ListaWplat.setWplaty(nowaWplata);
                NewPaymentAdapter npa = new NewPaymentAdapter(this, R.layout.nowa_wplata, listaWplat.getWplaty());
                setListAdapter(npa);

            }
            break;

    }


    String sumaCalkowita = getString(R.string.sumaCalkowita);
    sumaCalkowita = String.format(sumaCalkowita, getTempKarolina() + getTempLukasz() + getTempMarcelina());
    sum.setText(sumaCalkowita);

    String sumaSrednia = getString(R.string.sumaSrednio);
    sumaSrednia = String.format(sumaSrednia, (getTempKarolina() + getTempLukasz() + getTempMarcelina()) / 3);
    sumPerPerson.setText(sumaSrednia);
}

class NewPaymentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NowaWplata> {

    public LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public NewPaymentAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<NowaWplata> wplaty) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, wplaty);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        NowaWplata nowaWplata = getItem(position);
        Holder holder = null;

        if(view == null){
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nowa_wplata, null);

            TextView osobyWplata = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.osobaWplata);
            TextView kwotaWplaty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kwotaWplata);
            TextView opisWplaty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.opisWplata);

            holder = new Holder(osobyWplata, kwotaWplaty, opisWplaty);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }

        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(nowaWplata.getOsoba().toString());
        holder.osoba.setText("[" + nowaWplata.getDate() + "]  " + spannableString);

        holder.kwota.setText("- " + nowaWplata.getWplata() + "zł");
        holder.opis.setText(nowaWplata.getOpis());

        return view;
    }

}

static class Holder{
    public TextView osoba;
    public TextView kwota;
    public TextView opis;

    public Holder(TextView osoba, TextView kwota, TextView opis) {
        this.osoba = osoba;
        this.opis = opis;
        this.kwota = kwota;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this flag to the NowaWplata class:

```
class NowaWplata {
    int flag;
    public NowaWplata (String par1, String par2, String par3, int flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    ...
    }

}
```

Then create the instance in next way:

```
flag=2;
NowaWplata nowaWplata = new NowaWplata(marcelinaRadioButton.getText().toString(), addPrice.getText().toString(), description.getText().toString(), flag);
```

And update your NewPaymentAdapter.getView() method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    NowaWplata nowaWplata = getItem(position);
    Holder holder = null;

    if(view == null){
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nowa_wplata, null);

        TextView osobyWplata = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.osobaWplata);
        TextView kwotaWplaty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kwotaWplata);
        TextView opisWplaty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.opisWplata);

        holder = new Holder(osobyWplata, kwotaWplaty, opisWplaty);

        view.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
    }

    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(nowaWplata.getOsoba().toString());
    holder.osoba.setText("[" + nowaWplata.getDate() + "]  " + spannableString);

    holder.kwota.setText("- " + nowaWplata.getWplata() + "zł");
    holder.opis.setText(nowaWplata.getOpis());

    if(nowaWplata.flag==1){
        holder.osoba.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else if(nowaWplata.flag==2){
        holder.osoba.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }else if (nowaWplata.flag == 3) {
        holder.osoba.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }    

    return view;
}
```

Comment: glad to hear it! Please, don't forget to mark answer as correct and vote it up